# Borrowed RefCell does not last long enough when iterating over a list

Tags: linked-list, rust, smart-pointers

I'm trying to implement a linked list to understand smart pointers in Rust. I defined a `Node`:

```rust
use std::{cell::RefCell, rc::Rc};

struct Node {
    val: i32,
    next: Option<Rc<RefCell<Node>>>,
}
```

and iterate like

```rust
fn iterate(node: Option<&Rc<RefCell<Node>>>) -> Vec<i32> {
    let mut p = node;
    let mut result = vec![];

    loop {
        if p.is_none() {
            break;
        }

        result.push(p.as_ref().unwrap().borrow().val);

        p = p.as_ref().unwrap().borrow().next.as_ref();
    }

    result
}
```

the compiler reports an error:

```
error[E0716]: temporary value dropped while borrowed
  --> src/main.rs:27:13
   |
27 |         p = p.as_ref().unwrap().borrow().next.as_ref();
   |             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^              -
   |             |                                         |
   |             |                                         temporary value is freed at the end of this statement
   |             |                                         ... and the borrow might be used here, when that temporary is dropped and runs the destructor for type `std::cell::Ref<'_, Node>`
   |             creates a temporary which is freed while still in use
   |             a temporary with access to the borrow is created here ...
   |
   = note: consider using a `let` binding to create a longer lived value
```

What happened? Can't we use a reference to iterate on a node defined this way?

Comment: The recently updated [Learning Rust with Entirely Too Many Linked Lists](https://rust-unofficial.github.io/too-many-lists/) contains [a section](https://rust-unofficial.github.io/too-many-lists/fourth-iteration.html) that attempts to solve this *exact* problem. I *strongly* recommend you read it. The [chapter introduction](https://rust-unofficial.github.io/too-many-lists/fourth.html) contains the disclaimer: "[T]his chapter is basically a demonstration that this is a very bad idea."

Answer (score 5):

Instead of assigning `p` the borrowed reference, you need to clone the `Rc`:

```
use std::cell::RefCell;
use std::rc::Rc;

struct Node {
    val: i32,
    next: Option<Rc<RefCell<Node>>>,
}

fn iterate(node: Option<Rc<RefCell<Node>>>) -> Vec<i32> {
    let mut p = node;
    let mut result = vec![];

    loop {
        let node = match p {
            None => break,
            Some(ref n) => Rc::clone(n), // Clone the Rc
        };

        result.push(node.as_ref().borrow().val); //works because val is Copy
        p = match node.borrow().next {
            None => None,
            Some(ref next) => Some(Rc::clone(next)), //clone the Rc
        };
    }

    result
}

fn main() {
    let node = Some(Rc::new(RefCell::new(Node {
        val: 0,
        next: Some(Rc::new(RefCell::new(Node { val: 1, next: None }))),
    })));

    let result = iterate(node);
    print!("{:?}", result)
}
```

This is necessary because you are trying to use a variable with a shorter lifespan in a context that requires a longer lifespan. The result of `p.as_ref().unwrap().borrow()` is dropped (i.e. freed, de-allocated) after the loop iteration, but you are trying to use its members in the next loop (this is called `use after free` and one of the design goals of Rust is to prevent that).

The issue is that borrows do not own the object. If you want to use the `next` as `p` in the next loop, then `p` will have to own the object. This can be achieved with `Rc` (i.e. 'reference counted') and allows for multiple owners in a single thread.

> What if the definition of `Node::next` is `Option<Box<RefCell<Node>>>`, how to iterate over this list?

> Yes, I'm also very confused with `RefCell`, without `RefCell` we can iterate over list using reference only, but will fail with `RefCell`. I even tried to add a vector of `Ref` to save the reference, but still can not success.

If you drop the `RefCell` you can iterate it like this:

```
struct Node {
    val: i32,
    next: Option<Box<Node>>,
}

fn iterate(node: Option<Box<Node>>) -> Vec<i32> {
    let mut result = vec![];
    let mut next = node.as_ref().map(|n| &**n);

    while let Some(n) = next.take() {
        result.push(n.val);

        let x = n.next.as_ref().map(|n| &**n);
        next = x;
    }

    result
}

fn main() {
    let node = Some(Box::new(Node {
        val: 0,
        next: Some(Box::new(Node { val: 1, next: None })),
    }));

    let result = iterate(node);
    print!("{:?}", result)
}
```

Maybe it's possible with a `RefCell` as well, but I was not able to work around the lifetime issues.

Comment: What if the definition of Node.next is `Option<Box<RefCell<Node>>>`, how to iterate over this list?

Comment: Yes, I'm also very confused with RefCell, without RefCell we can iterate over list using reference only, but will fail with RefCell. I even tried to add a vector of Ref to save the reference, but still can not success.

Comment: @xudifsd if you try to preserve all the individual `Ref`s then you essentially create a self-referential struct, see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66400083/2189130) for a bit more info about iterating over nested `Rc<RefCell>`s.

Answer (score 0):

I bring a little different code from [above](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55332219/8047387) answer, one match expression in the loop.

```
fn iterate(node: Option<Rc<RefCell<ListNode>>>) -> Vec<i32>{
    let mut result = vec![];

    let mut p = match node{
        Some(x) => Rc::clone(&x),
        None => return result,
    };

    loop {
        result.push(p.as_ref().borrow().val); //works because val is Copy

        let node = match &p.borrow().next{
            Some(x) => Rc::clone(&x),
            None => break,
        };
        p = node;
    }

    result
}
```