# How to implement Iterator for a Rc<RefCell<T>> chain?

Tags: rust, iterator, smart-pointers, lifetime

When implementing a skip list in Rust, I got stuck when trying to implement `Iterator` for a `Rc<RefCell<T>>` chain.

```
pub struct SkipList<K, V> {
    head: Rc<RefCell<SkipNode<K, V>>>,
    rng: rand::rngs::ThreadRng,
    len: usize,
}

impl<K: Ord, V> SkipList<K, V> {
    pub fn iter(&self) -> Iter<K, V> {
        let next = &RefCell::borrow(&self.head).next_by_height[0];
        Iter {
            ptr: next.as_ref().map(|ref cell|Rc::clone(cell)),
            _marker: Default::default(),
        }
    }
}

struct SkipNode<K, V> {
    entry: Entry<K, V>,
    next_by_height: [Option<Rc<RefCell<SkipNode>>>; MAX_HEIGHT],
}

pub struct Entry<K, V> {
    key: K,
    value: V,
}

struct SkipNode<K, V> {
    entry: Option<Entry<K, V>>,
    next_by_height: SkipTrack<K, V>,
}

pub struct Iter<'a, K: Ord, V> {
    ptr: Option<Rc<RefCell<SkipNode<K, V>>>>,
    _marker: marker::PhantomData<&'a K>,
}

impl<'a, K, V: 'a> Iterator for Iter<'a, K, V>
where K: Ord
{
    type Item = Ref<'a, Entry<K, V>>;

    fn next(&mut self) -> Option<Self::Item> {
        self.ptr.take().map(|node| {
            let current = RefCell::borrow(&node);
            self.ptr = current.next_by_height[0].as_ref().map(|ref node| Rc::clone(node));
            Ref::map(current, |ref wrapped| {
                &wrapped.entry.unwrap()
            })
        })
    }
}
```

and the error is:

```
   Compiling RclessRefCelllessTgreatergreater-Rust v0.1.0 (/home/runner/RclessRefCelllessTgreatergreater-Rust)
error[E0515]: cannot return reference to temporary value
   --> main.rs:138:15
    |
138 |               &wrapped.entry.unwrap()
    |               ^----------------------
    |               ||
    |               |temporary value created here
    |               returns a reference to data owned by the current function

error[E0507]: cannot move out of `wrapped.entry` which is behind a shared reference
   --> main.rs:138:16
    |
138 |               &wrapped.entry.unwrap()
    |                ^^^^^^^^^^^^^
    |                |
    |                move occurs because `wrapped.entry` has type `std::option::Option<Entry<K, V>>`, which does not implement the `Copy` trait
    |                help: consider borrowing the `Option`'s content: `wrapped.entry.as_ref()`

error[E0515]: cannot return value referencing function parameter `node`
   --> main.rs:137:13
    |
135 |               let current = RefCell::borrow(&node);
    |                                             ----- `node` is borrowed here
136 |               self.ptr = current.next_by_height[0].as_ref().map(|ref node| Rc::clone(node));
137 | /             Ref::map(current, |ref wrapped| {
138 | |                 &wrapped.entry.unwrap()
139 | |             })
    | |______________^ returns a value referencing data owned by the current function

error: aborting due to 3 previous errors

Some errors have detailed explanations: E0507, E0515.
For more information about an error, try `rustc --explain E0507`.
error: could not compile `RclessRefCelllessTgreatergreater-Rust`.
```

the full code is available at [Repl.it](https://repl.it/@LebranceBW/RclessRefCelllessTgreatergreater-Rust).

I attempted to take the `Ref<T>` as the `Item` returned by `Iterator`, but the compiler complained that `next` could not return a temporary variable. Is there an elegant way to implement `Iterator` for `Rc<RefCell>`?

Comment: oh sorry. the code was written from my memory because no laptop at hand. I will provide a more detailed code tomorrow.

Comment: Also, implementing a data structure is not the most gentlest way to get acquainted with Rust. See [this book](https://rust-unofficial.github.io/too-many-lists/) for an introduction into the topic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there an elegant way to implement `Iterator` for `Rc<RefCell>`?

Not particularly. There's two big things in your way.

---

One limitation when building an `Iterator` is that the output type *cannot* reference the iterator itself. It can either return an owned value (no lifetimes involved) or return references bound to the lifetime of some other object.

I see you've tried to communicate that you want to return `Ref`s bound to the lifetime of the orignal `SkipList` by using `PhantomData<&'a K>` and also using `'a` in your `Iterator::Item`. However, since your iterator can only source values from `ptr`, an owned value with no lifetime-linkage to `'a`, the compiler will complain about mismatched lifetimes at one point or another.

In order to do this, your iterator would have to use something bound to `'a`, probably some form of `Option<Ref<'a, _>>`.

---

However, another limitation is when you have nested `RefCell`s, with each level that you iterate, you need to keep around an additional `Ref`. The reason being that borrows from a `Ref` don't keep the lifetime of the `RefCell`, but from the `Ref` itself.

```
let refc = RefCell::new(RefCell::new(RefCell::new(42)));
let ref1 = refc.borrow(); // these all need
let ref2 = ref1.borrow(); // to be preserved
let ref3 = ref2.borrow(); // to access `v`
let v = &*ref3;
```

So if you try to keep only one `Ref` chained from another, its going to encounter a *"returns a value referencing data owned by the current function"* error in one form or another. If you instead try to keep all those `Ref`s within the iterator, well then it creates a self-referential struct. Not nice.

You can only get out of this issue by cloning the `Rc`s at each level (which you've already done) to to get an owned value and escape the lifetime of the previous `Ref`.

---

So you cannot return a reference type for your iterator. Your only option is to return an owned value, which in this case wouldn't be ideal since it'd either have to be a *cloned* `Entry`, or an `Rc<RefCell<SkipNode<K, V>>>`, or a wrapper around an `Rc` that exposes the `Entry` properly.

Here's a working version. The `EntryRef` wrapper I added could probably be better but it works and demonstrates the point.

```
pub struct EntryRef<K, V> {
    ptr: Rc<RefCell<SkipNode<K, V>>>,
}

impl<K, V> EntryRef<K, V> {
    pub fn get_entry(&self) -> Ref<'_, Entry<K, V>> {
        Ref::map(self.ptr.borrow(), |node| node.entry.as_ref().unwrap())
    }
}

pub struct Iter<K: Ord, V> {
    ptr: Option<Rc<RefCell<SkipNode<K, V>>>>,
}

impl<K, V> Iterator for Iter<K, V>
where
    K: Ord,
{
    type Item = EntryRef<K, V>;

    fn next(&mut self) -> Option<Self::Item> {
        self.ptr.take().map(|node| {
            self.ptr = node.borrow().next_by_height[0]
                .as_ref()
                .map(|ref node| Rc::clone(node));
            EntryRef { ptr: node }
        })
    }
}
```

See also:

- [How do I write an iterator that returns references to itself?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30422177/how-do-i-write-an-iterator-that-returns-references-to-itself)
- [Why can't I store a value and a reference to that value in the same struct?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32300132/why-cant-i-store-a-value-and-a-reference-to-that-value-in-the-same-struct)
- [Borrowed RefCell does not last long enough when iterating over a list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55331919/borrowed-refcell-does-not-last-long-enough-when-iterating-over-a-list)